Is this explanation of chassis grounding correct?
In Henry Ott's Electromagnetic Compatibility Engineering, Section 3.2.5: Chassis Grounds explains that circuit ground should be connected to the chassis where the I/O cables come in, as shown:

This makes sense to me to improve shielding, as it ensures that the chassis is at the lowest potential, and not impacted by the voltage \$V_G\$ developed across the ground plane (due to the flow of current and the plane's finite impedance). However, Ott's explanation has to do with radiated emissions. He explains that if the circuit-to-chassis connection were to be on the opposite side, then the entire voltage \$V_G\$ will drive common-mode current onto the cable. On the other hand, with ground connected as shown, the voltage driving said current is ideally 0.
This explanation doesn't make sense to me. I don't understand how the position of the circuit-to-chassis connection can influence current somehow being sent out onto the I/O cable. As the chassis is only connected at one point, it should stay at that potential, but no current should ever flow across it (i.e. it shouldn't impact the flow of current).
He then explains why a low circuit-to-chassis impedance is needed: currents are being sent out towards ground, and the connections form a circuit divider between the I/O cable and the chassis connection. The chassis connection's low impedance therefore sends more common-mode noise current to the chassis than out to the cable. Again, I don't understand why any current would ever be pushed onto the chassis since it's connected at only one point.
Is this due to stray capacitances between the chassis and the I/O ground at high frequency? That would probably make sense, but I would've expected him to show that explicitly, so I assume I'm missing something?

Ultimately, we're modeling the effects of (often unpredictable) electromagnetic fields and near-field coupling effects as lumped circuits, so no analogy can be perfect here. We often need to use rather "artificial" assumptions, such as a voltage source that appear out of nowhere across across two points in space, an imaginary extra ground plane below our circuit, etc.

Remember that radiated emissions, incoming and outgoing, manifest themselves as current across the conducting metal surfaces they encounter. And incoming emissions like to take the easiest path to ground.

Like you see in the picture, the PCB has voltage Vg between its left and right ends.
If you ground the right side of PCB to the right side of the chassis, the whole cable coming out of left with all wires (grounds and signals) are now referenced to the left side noisy PCB ground (chassis + Vg), instead of just chassis potential.
Now the signals are referenced to left side of the PCB, which is also at chassis potential, so signals and grounds on cable have no PCB noise Vg added and are just at chassis potential.

So are we assuming that the chassis is the lowest potential in the system, and it can be used as a reference?

@AliShah That's s completely different thing. An everyday example is your computer, you can define some point like chassis to be 0V and you can have a -12V power supply which has even lower potential than 0V.

Consider two typical test scenarios:

This applies to both conducted and radiated.  Maybe the enclosure is bonded to reference plane in the test chamber (usually, set on a metal table and bonded with EMI tape), maybe it's sitting on it but insulated, or a standard elevation above it (setting capacitance to a relatively modest value), maybe it's suspended in air above the floor (low capacitance).  In any case, the enclosure always has some "reaction mass" against which the connector port can produce common mode emissions, at some frequency or range.
In a conducted test, the cable is terminated into a CDN (Coupling Decoupling Network), or for power lines, an ISN, LISN ((Line) Impedance Stabilization Network) or AMN (Artificial Mains Network), through which we can measure the conducted emissions directly (note that the spectrum analyzer, oscilloscope or other receiver has a resistive impedance, and resistance is flat vs. frequency hence "impedance stabilization").  Since the CDN has a resistive impedance, it also gives us a standard means of terminating the cable [CM], giving a more consistent setup to measure radiation from (the cable elevation, length and layout will also be specified in such a test).

If a system is "standalone" with a cable or device permanently attached -- maybe there's another enclosure at the end, maybe it's just a light or switch or sensor or something, it doesn't really matter -- there's no opportunity to put a CDN on it, and maybe not even a current probe (most standards ignore cables under a certain length, say a meter or several).  But we still have the dipole geometry where the enclosure acts as one element, the cable another, and thus we have coupling into radiation from the connector port.
At the face of the enclosure, at the highest frequencies (probably ~GHz), the cable looks like a "long" 1/4 wave whip antenna over ground plane, so will have some modest impedance and probably a multi-lobed radiation pattern (depending on cable length, and where and how it bends; it may also act like a Goubau line, then the far end scatters incident waves, acting like a secondary point source).  At lower frequencies where diffraction makes the face not look like a plane anymore, the bulk of the body looks like an oddly shaped monopole element, and thus forms an asymmetrical dipole with the cable.  At the lowest frequencies, they look like an electrically-short dipole (electric field / capacitance dominant).
Depending on the relative length between cable and enclosure, and their proximity to nearby things (e.g. maybe the cable is routed along a steel beam; maybe the enclosure is floating, supported on fiberglass brackets; lots of possibilities), there can be capacitive (or transmission line) loading effect.  This affects loop capacitance in the above conducted scenario.
In any case, for the port equivalent circuit, I think you can see that the voltage at the base of the cable, as seen from the outside, will be exactly the VG inside the enclosure, if the ground is made at the opposite end of the board.
Other notes or insights:

We're working in the space of dynamical systems.  Dynamical systems have solutions (response, resonant modes, etc.), regardless of where the excitation comes from -- including the complete absence thereof.

Even if we aren't modeling full fields, we usually have equivalent RLC or transmission line circuits in play.  Spotting those elements, is nontrivial of course, but appreciate at least that equivalent circuits can be created.

Dynamical systems for EMI are [almost always] LTI (linear time-invariant).  Thus, superposition applies, and the response of some system will have the same modes (e.g. resonant peaks), whether we're measuring transfer gain (e.g. gain from VG to radiated field) or self-impedance (backscattering, i.e. radiated to radiated field, absorption and reflection).  The exact magnitude, phase, even asymptotic behavior, may vary, but the frequency breakpoints (poles and zeroes) are characteristic.
(For testing purposes, we aren't usually very interested in port or cable impedances.  There are some instances where current injection is specified, and thus some impedance must be achieved.  But for conducted and radiated immunity, it's just voltage or waveforms applied to the system.  In any case, as designers, we're still interested in what the system response is, to understand and cover all these cases.)

These systems are reciprocal, i.e. the gain from radiated field to connector port equals the gain from connector port to radiated field.  Anything we do to it, it can do back in turn.  (What the circuit absorbs, reflects, or transmits, is an independent matter, however.)

Phrasing: Ott says "...voltage VG will drive common-mode current onto the cable." This is strictly incorrect, because it's... well it's voltage. Playing fast and loose with voltage and current is somewhat justified (and thus one of the underlying assumptions in EMC) because everything has some impedance, and thus I = V/Z.  But notice that Z arises from the system dynamics: the cable impedance and termination, radiation resistance, and the enclosure "reaction" impedance (whether hard grounded, in proximity to metal, or in free space).  So by speaking in terms of current, we already need to know about the system's response, the impedance.  But it kind of doesn't matter, because we need to know that anyway.  It would be most accurate to say something general, like a "source of excitation", than to say voltage or current -- but, given this understanding, it also kind of doesn't matter; hence, the tendency to play fast and loose with terminology here.

There is the capacitance between PCB and enclosure, however this is a minor effect -- the geometry resembles a wide stripline type transmission line -- at most causing "grounding" at the resonant frequencies, and even then, such "ground" is only localized to respective "node" locations on the board (where the resonant voltage approaches zero, i.e. λ/2 away from the ground point).  In particular, note that this capacitance draws current from VG, but not "all of it", it makes a parallel branch with the connector impedance.  In general (over wide frequency ranges), it simply modifies the source impedance, and doesn't have much effect on the connector port CM voltage and impedance.



I think that mostly makes sense then. Indeed, once the parasitic capacitances are considered, his explanation is a lot easier to understand. However, I then wonder: why bother grounding to chassis at all? If the chassis is bonded to the ground plane, then of course, it ensures stable ground, but if the chassis is suspended in the air, then what is the advantage of connecting the circuit ground to the chassis?

If the chassis is floating, what is it doing?  It can short out inhomogeneous fields, but remains as a capacitive divider between [cable CM/ground], Vg and the surroundings. That is, high frequencies that could otherwise radiate directly off the board (multipole radiation pattern) are reflected inside and at most are forced to exit via the connector port, but low frequencies for which a dipole (vs. cable) or monopole (electric field, i.e. capacitive) equivalent applies, are mostly or completely unaffected.
